# Ошибка в решении задачи python

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, только начал изучать и не могу понять, где накосячил
1) Попросите пользователя ввести 2 числа.
2) Сохраните в переменную результат деления первого числа на второе при условии, что делитель не равен 0. Если делитель равен 0, то сохранить в переменную строку: «бесконечность».
3) Вывести пользователю ответ в таком виде: «ЧИСЛО_1 / ЧИСЛО_2 = ОТВЕТ».
Мое решение выглядит как-то так

```
my_num1 = input("Введите число 1 ")
my_num2 = input("Введите число 2 ")
if my_num2 == 0:
chislo = "бесконечность"
else:
my_num_final = int(my_num1) / int(my_num2)
```

В итоге при запуске ругается на chislo = "бесконечность"

Comment: С отступами разберитесь, в Питоне это элемент синтаксиса

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, то поясните, пожалуйста

Comment: попробовал переписать так - не помогло

Comment: my_num1 = input("Введите число 1 ")
my_num2 = input("Введите число 2 ")
my_num1 = int(my_num1)
my_num2 = int(my_num2)
if my_num2 == false:
chislo = "бесконечность"
else:
my_num_final = my_num1/my_num2
print my_num_final

Comment: А как ругается? "Что вы мне тут подсунули? ". Или как то иначе? Ваше решение выглядит так,  или как-то так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на отступы

```
my_num1 = int(input("Введите число 1 "))
my_num2 = int(input("Введите число 2 "))
if my_num2 == 0:
    chislo = "бесконечность"
else:
    my_num_final = my_num1 / my_num2
```

и на приведение ввода к целому, чтобы можно было сравнивать `my_num2` с числом нуль

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Введите два числа:") 
a = input() 
b = input()

cond = a != "0"
if cond:
    x = int(b) / int(a)
    print("x = ", x) else:
    x = "бесконечность"
    print("x = ", x)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
number1 = input("Введите первое число:")
print("Вы ввели:", number1)

number2 = input("Введите второе число:")
print("Вы ввели:", number2)

if number2 == "0":
    print("Поделить невозможно")

print("Результат деления =", int(number1) / int(number2))
```

Единственное НО не могу разобраться как вывести число 1 поделенное на число 2 и ответ. как это так вывести

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос. а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативный вариант **@MBo**:

```
my_num1 = input("Введите число 1 ")
my_num2 = input("Введите число 2 ")
if my_num2 == '0': chislo = "бесконечность"
else: my_num_final = int(my_num1) / int(my_num2)
```

Или понятнее:

```
my_num1 = input("Введите число 1 ")
my_num2 = input("Введите число 2 ")
if my_num2 == '0': 
    chislo = "бесконечность"
else: 
    my_num_final = int(my_num1) / int(my_num2)
```

Comment: А отступов тут не нужно - сократил в строку

Comment: И всё же это не по стайл гайдам. Лучше переносить и с отступами, так код нагляднее

Comment: @CraxyElf исправил

Comment: А исправленный вариант не отличается от варианта MBo, насколько я вижу. Получается, нет смысла в вашем ответе, извините :)

Comment: У @MBo работает в типе `int`, у меня - в `str`. Отличия есть, не понял, как вы их не заметили

Comment: А, вижу )))  Ну, удачи, я думаю большинство тех, кто будет смотреть ваш код не увидит разницы так же как и я

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю как-то так должно быть

```
a = input("Введите первое число a: ")

b = input("Введите второе число b: ")

if int(a)/int(b) != 0:
    rez = int(a)/int(b)
    print("a/b = ", rez)

elif int(a)/int(b) == 0:
    rez = "бесконечность"
    print("a/b = ", rez)
print(a, "/", b, "=", rez)
```

Comment: Зачем вы бежите впереди поезда? Автор не говорил, что ему нужно, а вы только делаете никому не нужные догадки

Comment: К тому же, зачем постоянно делать `int(a)` и `int(b)`, если можно сделать `int(input(...))`?